# Updating X and Y coordinates given a distance and a ratio?

Tags: java, math

I am working on a project in Java that describes a car driving a given distance. The function drive has three parameters: one for the distance traveled, one for the x ratio, and one for the y ratio. 
Here is a description of the function:

> drive(int distance, double xRatio, double yRatio) should take the
>   desired  distance to travel as an integer, and two double values
>   which, together,  specify the direction as a ratio of horizontal to
>   vertical distances. For  example, if xRatio = 1 and yRatio = 2, for
>   every 1 unit to the right  (positive x), the car would travel 2 units
>   up (positive y). Negative values  for xRatio and yRatio correspond to
>   moving left and down, respectively.  Given the distance and direction,
>   this method should correctly compute the  ending coordinates
>   (truncated to integers). It should also correctly  subtract the amount
>   of fuel used. If the distance specified requires greater  than the
>   amount of fuel that the car currently has, the car should travel as 
>   far as it can until it is empty and print this text to the console:
>   "Ran out  of gas after driving x miles." (with the correct value
>   substituted in for x). The method should return the number of miles
>   which were actually driven.

Here is what I have of the drive function so far:

```
public double drive(int distance, double xRatio, double yRatio)
    {
        double a = xRatio;
        double b = yRatio;
        double r = 0;

        r = (a*a) + (b*b);
        r = Math.sqrt(r);

        double finalX = (xRatio * distance) / r;
        double finalY = (yRatio * distance) / r;

        return 0;

    }
```

I have the final coordinates of the car, but I'm not sure how to start working out how the gas gets updated as the car travels and how to stop it if it runs out of gas. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a math question or a programming question?

Comment: Why are you returning 0?

Comment: Both I suppose. One thing I'm hoping to find is the correct mathematical way to use the xRatio, yRatio, and distance to get the end coordinates. I believe what I have now is the correct way to do that part, but if not I would like to know.

It is returning 0 right now as a place holder. I do not know the actual distance traveled yet, which is what the method should return.

Comment: This is Math question.

Comment: Are you asking about the final coordinates or about the gas usage? You've made no attempt at the gas usage so that wouldn't be appropriate to ask here. As to the final coordinates - that's a mathematics question, unless you know the formula but have problems implementing it in java which doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

gasRemaining is a variable that represents the miles left that the gas will let you drive

```
public double drive(int distance, double xRatio, double yRatio)
{
    double a = xRatio;
    double b = yRatio;
    double r = 0;

    r = (a*a) + (b*b);
    r = Math.sqrt(r);

if (distance > gasRemaining){
    system.out.println("Ran out of gas after driving " + gasRemaining + " miles");


    double finalX = (xRatio * gasRemaining) / r;
    double finalY = (yRatio * gasRemaining) / r;

    gasRemaining = 0;

    return 0;
}

else {
    double finalX = (xRatio * distance) / r;
    double finalY = (yRatio * distance) / r;

    gasRemaining = gasRemaining - distance;

    return 0;  
}
}
```